# Sql Query Generation Using bat file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a requirement where i need to see data for every week using a sql query.

I used query like `SELECT * from table Between '27-08-2012' and '30-08-2012'`.

Now my requirement is that i need a batch file that can given me this script based on user selection. Like user can give start date and end date and sql query should generate automatically.

Answer (score 1):

A much less error prone way to get a date range is to use a graphical date picker
than manual user input which has to be checked for validity.
(month/day names will match your locale, not my German one)

[image: Graphical date picker]

This PowerShell script:

```
# Function Pick-Date
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
Function Pick-Date { 
  $Cal = new-object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
  $Cal.ShowWeekNumbers = $true 
  $Cal.MaxSelectionCount = 10 # change this value for the max date distance
  $Cal.Dock = 'Fill' 
  $Form = new-object Windows.Forms.Form 
  $Form.text = "Drag the mouse to select a date range then hit [enter]" 
  $Form.Size = new-object Drawing.Size @(656,620) 
  $btnSelect = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $btnSelect.Size = "1,1"
  $btnSelect.add_Click({ $Form.close() }) 
  $Form.Controls.Add($btnSelect ) 
  $Form.AcceptButton = $btnSelect
  $Form.Controls.Add($Cal) 
  $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})  
  [void]$Form.showdialog() 
  return ("SELECT * from table Between '"+
         (Get-Date($Cal.SelectionStart) -format 'dd-MM-yyyy')+
         "' and '"+
         (Get-Date($Cal.SelectionEnd) -format 'dd-MM-yyyy')+
         "'")
} 
Pick-Date
```

Will have this output, you can save to a `file.sql`

```
PS> .\Pick-Date.ps1
SELECT * from table Between '27-08-2012' and '31-08-2012'
```

**EDIT**

This batch wrapper for the powerShell script will store the query in the variable `SqlQuery`

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
::Wrap Pick-Date.ps1 in same folder as batch

For /F "delims=" %%%A in (
  'Powershell -NoP -NonI -NoLogo -File Pick-Date.ps1 '
) Do Set "SqlQuery=%%A"

Set SqlQuery
```

Comment: If you go to the trouble of `new-object` forms, why not go the whole 9 yards and `new-object` a `SqlConnection` and use proper parameterized queries, in the process also avoiding all the issues with date format locales (`dd-MM` vs `MM-dd` vs `dd/MM` etc)

Comment: @RemusRusanu I agree, but it's not me to go the additional yards ;-). Date picking may be isolated from the rest (even be wrapped in an ugly batch) but I don't know OPs skills in PowerShell. As it is my answer might even be considered off topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot now I have to make a bat file run this with out going to command prompt . And prompting the sql query

Comment: @LotPings can we make the script prompt the query after date selection rather that giving at command line

Comment: @AmarReddy Added a batch wrapper to my answer, batch and ps1 script have to reside in the same folder.